# Steps for Cloud Function + Cloud Build API + Node 10?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry

As I received email from Firbase to upgrade Firebase Cloud Function with Node 10 and Cloud Build API.

[image]

I have done all the steps as below:

- Updated to the "Blaze" pay-as-you-go Plan
- Updated Node.js 10 runtime
- Enabled Cloud Build API

Now what?

I am just sending notification when some data get updated in **Cloud Firestore** in my old cloud function.

Will the same function will work which I have used before? or Do I need to do something with Cloud Build API?

Can anyone please suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now what?

If you did everything requested, and everything works as you expect, then you're done.

> Will the same function will work which I have used before?

It should.  Test it and see if it works.  If it doesn't, redeploy it and try again.

> or Do I need to do something with Cloud Build API?

There's nothing you need to do.  The Cloud Build process is managed by the Firebase CLI.

Answer (score 0):

The function will still work as it used to. The main difference is that the build of the function itself is going to be done using Cloud Build, thus why activating the Cloud Build API is needed.

This is a great change as it will ease the process of debugging Cloud Function deployments as the build steps will be shown under Cloud Build in the Cloud Console. This opens access to logs as well as access to each of the steps happening during the deployment process, hence more visibility for the user.